# How to add a second title to a view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a list ordered on a specific field. The value of this field contains yes/no.

So the list first displays all rows with yes. After that all rows with no are displayed.

I would like to display a second title before all rows with no. How to do this?

Comment: Did you try adding [Global: Custom Text] ? What are the filters and fields here? A screenshot would really help.

Comment: Hi Justme, thanks for accepting my answer, please up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make 2 views, first view (main view) with "yes" filter. second with "no" filter, then in first view add a footer (Global: View area), place there your second view, on each view set your title as needed. you can also pass parameters in view settings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you have defined the yes/no field. If it is a boolean field, you can use the grouping function of views. This grouping functionality allows you group content with a shared value, which will be displayed as a header.

So you add your field to the view (optionally exclude it from display to hide it from each row), then under format settings (top left of the views config page) enable grouping for this field. You now have 2 sub-headings in your view showing something like ON and OFF.

For boolean fields you can override these values with custom values (not sure about other option fields):

[image: overridden formatting]

Resulting in the following view:

[image: Result]