# How to place multi view in one page?

Tags: views, theming

I have two content types and I wanna place two content views in one page with different display modes.
How to solve it?

Comment: make the 2 views, on main view add a footer in midle column, there  look for 'global: view area', add your second view to footer

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I wanna place two content views in one view area.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240079/how-to-add-a-second-title-to-a-view/240091#240091

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Attachment to a view.

[image]

And Page: filter -> contenttype 1
    Attachment: filter -> contenttype2